# MySQL Many to Many query confusion

Tags: mysql, sql

I've looked at a bunch of questions and solutions regarding many to many queries. I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. Maybe I'm not completely understanding the keywords in MySQL. But...

I have 3 tables. The first table is a list of peoples contact information. The second table is a list of mailing list categories. The third table is an associative table that holds the `id's` from the first and second table. How would I write a `MySQL` query to get all the contacts from the contact table that match the `VIP list id` (which I already have)?

**Table 1 (contacts)**

```
id  |  name  |  email
-----------------------------
1   |  John  | john@gmail.com
-----------------------------
2   |  Jane  | jane@gmail.com
-----------------------------
```

**Table 2 (list_type)**

```
id  | list_name |
-----------------
1   |  VIP's    |
-----------------
2   |  Generic  | 
-----------------
```

**Table 3 (list_contact_joiner)**

```
contact_id  | list_type_id |
----------------------------
    1       |      2       |
----------------------------
    2       |      1       | 
----------------------------
```

**This is what I tried but get a syntax error**

```
$listID = 1;

SELECT list_contact_joiner.contact_id 
FROM list_contact_joiner 
WHERE list_id = $listID AS lcj 
INNER JOIN contact_lists AS cl 
ON cl.id = lcj.contact_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contacts c
JOIN list_contact_joiner j on j.contact_id = c.id
JOIN list_type t on j.list_type_id = t.id
WHERE t.list_name = 'VIP''s'
```

If you already have the `id` of `VIP's` then you need to join only 2 tables

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contacts c
JOIN list_contact_joiner j on j.contact_id = c.id
WHERE j.list_type_id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the second version since I already have the list ID available. Can you breifly explain the `ON` keyword?

Comment: If you join 2 tables you need to define the columns that connect both together. You do that in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the join statement is not correct. It should be something as

```
select
c.name,
c.email,
lt.list_type
from list_contact_joiner lcj 
join contacts c on c.id = lcj.contact_id
join list_type lt on lt.id = lcj.list_type_id
where 
lt.id = ?
```

If you are looking for data with `$listID = 1;` then the place holder is
`lt.id = ?`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is because all the table specification (FROM and JOIN) has to occur before the WHERE and you got your alias syntax a little messed up - this should work better:

```
$listID = 1;

SELECT lcj.contact_id 
FROM list_contact_joiner AS lcj
INNER JOIN contact_lists AS cl 
ON cl.id = lcj.contact_id
WHERE lcj.list_id = $listID
```

But if all you are trying to do is get the `contact_id` then you don't need to do any join at all...

```
SELECT contact_id
FROM list_contact_joiner
WHERE list_id = $listID
```

If you need the rest of the contact information then you might try this:

```
SELECT contact.*
FROM list_contact_joiner
JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = list_contact_joiner.contact_id
WHERE list_id = $listID
```

Note that you still don't need to get the list_type table at all.